# Edge swipe back is not working when NavigationBar is hidden

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement the function that NavigationBar shrinks when scrolling WKWebView.

When the NavigationBar is shown, edge swipe works without problems, but nothing happens when NavigationBar is hidden.

This works with UITableView even if the NavigationBar is hidden, but it seems to happen only about WebView.

As another way, I used the "[AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar)", but since it causes a bug when used for WebView, so I decide to implement it myself.

When implementing such a function, how can implement it without bugs, and enable edge swiping even about WebView?